# How to identify groups of rows in SQL where the "latest" row in the group meets a certain condition?

Tags: sql

Let's imagine I have this table:

| zone_id | subzone_id | recency | operation |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 801 | 01 | 0 | 1 |
| 801 | 01 | 1 | 1 |
| p13 | 01 | 6 | 0 |
| p13 | 01 | 7 | 1 |

I am grouping the rows in this table based on `zone_id` and `subzone_id`. Rows which share the same values across these columns are considered to belong to the same group.

So, in the above example, the first two rows would belong to one group (`A`), and the second two rows would belong to another group (`B`)

What I am trying (but failing miserably) to do is keep only the groups of rows where the row with the lowest `recency` within the group has an `operation` which is NOT equal to 0.

In the above example, group `B` would therefore be removed, since the row within this group with the lowest `recency` (6) does indeed have an `operation` equal to 0.

Therefore only group `A` should remain:

| zone_id | subzone_id | recency | operation |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 801 | 01 | 0 | 1 |
| 801 | 01 | 1 | 1 |

I've tried using GROUP BY and ROW_NUMBER in my solution but I just can't make this work.

Comment: Is `recency` unique *inside* a group?

Comment: So which dbms is this???

Comment: "I've tried using GROUP BY and ROW_NUMBER in my solution".  Where?  We don't see your try in this post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make use of *first_value* window function:

```
with o as (
select *, 
  First_Value(operation) 
    over(partition by zone_id, subzone_id order by recency, operation) op
from t
)
select * 
from o
where op != 0;
```

Comment: this was precisely the function I needed but didn't know existed. Straightforward answer highly, highly appreciated (especially given the useless comments on my original question, above). Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution using SQL server without using any window function. A normal approach.

```
with cte AS
(
  select zone_id , subzone_id , min(recency) as min_recency from tbl_zone as a
  group by zone_id , subzone_id
)  
select a.* from tbl_zone as a INNER JOIN
(
    select a.zone_id , a.subzone_id , a.min_recency , b.operation 
    from cte as a INNER JOIN tbl_zone as b on 
    a.zone_id = b.zone_id and a.subzone_id = b.subzone_id and a.min_recency = b.recency
    and b.operation <> 0
) as b on a.zone_id = b.zone_id and a.subzone_id = b.subzone_id;
```